# One or more of the required values are missing although all prompt values have been selected

Tags: cognos

In my COGNOS prompt page, I have a button 'Generate'. On click of it, I call the script:

```
function generateReport(format) { 
        if(!canSubmitPrompt())
                       return;
...
..
}
```

Now although all the 'Required' Prompts on the page have been selected, I still get the error : `'One or more of the required values are missing. Required values are needed to produce the report.'` 
I also checked that all the filters on the main query subject that uses the Prompts are Optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a hidden block on the parameter page with some required parameters. That was the cause of the problem. The hidden block was removed and that solved it.
Thanks everyone for reading.